# Reinstall ubuntu on VPS

Tags: 22.04

I am using VPS server and its running latest version of ubuntu i.e. 22.04. How can I reinstall the ubuntu on my VPS server using command line. I tried to all the possible solution but on of it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can't reinstall the operating system while the operating system is running.

Since this is a VPS and you presumably don't have physical access to the server, you will need to follow the instructions from your VPS provider.

Typically, VPS providers will have a control panel where you can select a preinstalled system image with Ubuntu that you can use to overwrite your current installation.

Comment: If then is it possible to factory reset a VPS.

Comment: Different VPS providers have different toolkits. You can't use Ubuntu for this. You have to use the VPS provider's toolkit so you will need to follow the instructions/documentation for your particular VPS provider. If they don't have good documentation, or if you don't understand it, you need to ask your VPS provider for support.

Comment: Thank you so much.